# Why is the corner of my layer doing this?

Tags: bed-leveling

[image: printing a single layer square 80mmx80mm]
Trying to get my printer leveled correctly so I can make some stuff. Started printing this square and the back left corner is not getting enough adhesion. The front left and back right corners are fine. I think I need to either lower or raise the back left corner but not sure which... I try to tell what to do from how opacity of the layer but can't get a good reading.

Should I raise or lower back left corner of the layer?

Comment: Just lowered the back left corner a tiny bit thinking it was a little thin. Will post results!

Comment: Didn't work.. might've turned it too much

Comment: Have you cleaned and degreased the bed?

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet?